# MUI transitions work on chrome desktop , safari mobile, but absolutely ignored on chrome iOS?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Any idea how to solve the issue of chrome IOS absolutely don't work with MUI transitions like zoom grow slide, did anyone have this issue? the docs don't say anything about it

[Docs](https://v4.mui.com/components/transitions/#zoom)